# Does iPhone/iPad support mouseout event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, ipad

The Apple developer documentation says "mouseout" event is supported on IOS;

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

But I haven't seen any example of that...Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says:

> If the user taps a clickable element, events arrive in this order:
>   mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, and click. The mouseout
>   event occurs only if the user taps on another clickable item.

What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: What would clickable item include (apart from <a> tags)

Comment: Any element that supports the [HTML onclick attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) (or [HTML5 HTMLElement interface](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#htmlelement)), which is pretty much all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late answer - practical solution how to achieve onmouseout use:

```
$('*').on('click', function(){ return true; });
```

This way when you click somewhere on the page the mouseout will be fired.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Adding an event handler to every element on the DOM, no thanks.

Comment: I think the comment above this one is hugely understating. This solutions is *extremely bad* for performance. Do not use is.
$('body').on.... would be a much better approach.